# Getting error when oneTimeSetup method has fixture scope="session"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, conftest

I have implemented the selenium python framework using unittest and pytest with the page object model.
I have created a conftest.py file with oneTimeSetup method which will initialize the webdriver and then it will be used by all my test files. Below is the approach I've used. I have created the webdriver factory like this below

`WebDriverFactory.py`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
class WebDriverFactory():
    def __init__(self,browser):
        self.browser = browser

    def get_browser_instance(self):
        if self.browser == "FF":
            driver = webdriver.Firefox()

        elif self.browser == "Chrome":
            driver = webdriver.Chrome()

        elif self.browser == "IE":
            driver = webdriver.Ie()

        else:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome()


        baseUrl = "http://live.demoguru99.com/index.php/"
        driver.delete_all_cookies()
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        driver.get(baseUrl)

        return driver
```

`conftest.py`:

```
import pytest
from base.WebDriverFactory import WebDriverFactory

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser")

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def browser(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--browser")

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def oneTimeSetup(request,browser):
    print("This is one time setup")
    wdf = WebDriverFactory(browser)
    driver = wdf.get_browser_instance()

    if request.cls is not None:
        request.cls.driver = driver

    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

Below is my test file:

```
from pages.mobile_page.mobile_page import MobilePage
from utilities.mark_test_status import MarkTestStatus
import unittest
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("oneTimeSetup")
class TestMobile(unittest.TestCase):

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def classObject(self,oneTimeSetup):
        self.mb = MobilePage(self.driver)
        self.ts = MarkTestStatus(self.driver)

    def test_Mobile(self):
        result = self.mb.mobile()
        self.ts.finalMark(testcase="Mobile Sort By test",result=result,resultMessage="Testing Mobile SOrt functionality")
```

I am getting the below error when running the test in cmd.
[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQgsy.png)

If I change the scope for my oneTimeSetup to "class" in conftest.py, the test runs fine. But I am looking to run all mt test's in a single webdriver session when I add more tests.

Details:
Selenium Python v 3.1.41.0
Chrome 86.0.4240.111
pytest 6.0.1

Comment: Well, the message says it all: the `request` fixture has the `cls` attribute set only if the caller fixture is class-scoped. You should be able to enhance the check with smth like `if hasattr(request, "cls") and request.cls is not None:` though.

Comment: Thanks I added below                                                                                                           if hasattr(request, "cls") and request.cls is not None:
        request.cls.driver = driver                                                                                              and it worked. However I didnt understand what made the difference. Could you explain the significance of it please?

Answer (score 0):

oneTimeSetup fixture is session level and session level request parameter does not have cls attribute.
So rather than accessing request.cls like this

```
if request.cls is not None:
    request.cls.driver = driver
```

use request.node.items and setattr for individual item like this

```
session = request.node
for item in session.items:
    cls = item.getparent(pytest.Class)
    setattr(cls.obj, "driver", driver)
```